# python - how to Interpolate NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

Is there a way to interpolate Nan values of P & C in final_df (where str is a range with equal step) ??

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df0 = pd.DataFrame({'str': [var for var in range(700,1260,5)]})
print(df0)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'str': [700,705,710,715,720,1095,1100,1105,1110,1115,1120,1125,1130,1135,1205,1210,1215,1220,1225,1230,1235,1240,1245,1250,1255],
 'P': [0.075,0.075,0.075,0.075,0.075,17.95,19.75,21.85,24.25,26.55,29.2,31.9,35.05,37.7,98.6,102.15,108.5,113.5,118.4,123.55,127.3,132.7,138.7,142.7,148.35],
 'C': [407.8,403.65,398.3,391.65,387.8,30.05,26.65,23.7,21.35,19.65,16.05,14.3,11.95,9.95,0.475,0,0.525,0,0.2,0.175,0.15,0.375,0.125,0.075,0.175]})

df = pd.merge(df0,df1, on="str", how="outer")
print(df)
```

*df.interpolate(method ='cubic', limit_direction ='both')* seems not working...

Comment: Use inplace=True to save and view your values.

Answer (score 1):

I find `inplace=True` missing from your code. Insert this in your interpolate to replace the Nan values.

```
df.interpolate(method='cubic', limit_direction='both', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I'm still getting not the chart that I expected (falling P to negative, then upside, C - ok) - therefore am trying either to change method OR perhaps should I try scipy.interpolate better? I'm a little bit confused yet, but thanks for your answer... (perhaps will find the way to alter the question - will post here) OR do you know the equivalent of the operetion in scipy.interpolate ? `df['ot'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['P'] if x['str']<1105 else x['C'], axis=1` is needed to be plotted finally after interpolate (where P is initially falling under zero)... but need ~ mirror view

Comment: ... am just getting strange interpolation... anyway, thanks